# When building list of solutions with MSBuild how do I copy all outputs to another folder?

Tags: msbuild

We've got a large amount of legacy code in a big folder tree of solutions and projects, many of which we are not interested in (but unfortunately can't move at the moment)

We are currently using MSBuild to compile the solutions we are interested in like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Solutions Include="some_path\solution1.sln"
  <Solutions Include="some_other_path\solution2.sln"
  <Solutions Include="yet_another_path\solution3.sln"
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="Rebuild">
  <MSBuild Projects=@(Solutions) Targets="Rebuild" />
</Target>
```

This builds things just fine but what we would like to do is take all the files that end up in the various projects `bin\Release` folders to a different tree structure that has the same relative folders but a different root.

How can we do this **without** just looking for a particular file pattern (eg all the dll or exe files) as the file structure we have contains many files that we are not interested in.

So basically is there a way to find all the files our build script is building and move them to another place retaining their relative paths?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried overriding the Output path?

```
<MSBuild Projects="@(Solutions)"              Properties="OutputPath=$(ParentDir)\Output\%(Solutions.Filename)"/>
```

This will put the outputs of each solution in a tree from $(ParentDir)\Output.

Comment: That is close but each of the solutions in the build file contain multiple projects - which build their files to different folders. When I use your suggested answer I get one folder for each solution, but those folders contain all the files built for all of the projects in the solution. Rather than having a subfolder for each project which is what I'm after.

Comment: then build using the projects instead. *.csproj not sln. The're not needed anyway.

Comment: Unfortunately in my simplified example you can't see that there are 200 projects (in 10 solutions) and we're trying to avoid having to explicitly list them all.
If we have to list them all we might just go through and change all the "Output path" settings in Visual Studio instead so we don't have to worry about build orders etc

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 ideas for you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="AllTargetsWrapped">

    <!--
        <UsingTask AssemblyFile="$(ProgramFiles)\MSBuild\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.dll" TaskName="Version"/>
        -->
    <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets" />

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TPath Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\ExtensionPack\4.0\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks')">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\ExtensionPack\4.0\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks</TPath>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Import Project="$(TPath)"/>

    <PropertyGroup>
        <!-- Always declare some kind of "base directory" and then work off of that in the majority of cases  -->
        <WorkingCheckout>.</WorkingCheckout>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Target Name="AllTargetsWrapped">
        <CallTarget Targets="ShowVariables" />
        <CallTarget Targets="ShowMeTheFiles" />

    </Target>

    <Target Name="ShowVariables">
        <Message Text=" $_WorkingCheckout_ = '$(WorkingCheckout)' " />

        <Message Text=" $_MSBuildExtensionsPath32_ = '$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)' " />
        <Message Text=" $_MSBuildProjectDirectory_ = '$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)' " />

    </Target>

    <Target Name="ShowMeTheFiles">

        <ItemGroup>
            <AllFiles Include="$(WorkingCheckout)\**\*.*" />
        </ItemGroup>
        <MSBuild.Community.Tasks.RegexMatch Expression="\d+" Input="%(AllFiles.FullPath)">
            <Output TaskParameter="Output" ItemName="MatchedFiles" />
        </MSBuild.Community.Tasks.RegexMatch>       


        <Message Text="rootdir + directory + filename + extension: @(MatchedFiles->'%(rootdir)%(directory)%(filename)%(extension)')"/>

       <Copy
            SourceFiles="@(MatchedFiles)"
            DestinationFiles="@(MatchedFiles->'C:\WUTEMP\DestinationFolder\01\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')"
        />

        <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.FileSystem.FindUnder TaskAction="FindFiles" Path="$(WorkingCheckout)\" SearchPattern="F*">
            <Output ItemName="AllFilesStartingWithF" TaskParameter="FoundItems"/>
        </MSBuild.ExtensionPack.FileSystem.FindUnder>       

        <Message Text="rootdir + directory + filename + extension: @(AllFilesStartingWithF->'%(rootdir)%(directory)%(filename)%(extension)')"/>

        <Copy
            SourceFiles="@(AllFilesStartingWithF)"
            DestinationFiles="@(AllFilesStartingWithF->'C:\WUTEMP\DestinationFolder\02\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')"
        />      


    </Target>


</Project>
```

But I think the RecursiveDir is getting whacked in the conversion  :<

Comment: I don't think you can do what you need with any known task...to my knowledge.  You need "special" logic, which means a custom msbuild task.  If you've never written one, they're not that bad.  Let me see if I can find an old example.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a stubbed custom MSBuild task.
You can alter the "RunMyCustomKeeperLogic" logic to whatever you want.
I stubbed it as "keep every 5th file" as a dumbed down example.

Once you have the files back in the ".msbuild" world, you can copy/move do whatever you want with them.

```
namespace GranadaCoder.Framework.CrossDomain.MSBuild.Tasks.IO
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using Microsoft.Build.Utilities;

    public abstract class FileBasedTaskBase : Task
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Converts the delimited source file string to and IList.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sourceFilesString">The source files string.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        protected IList<string> ConvertSourceFileStringToList(string sourceFilesString)
        {
            IList<string> returnList = sourceFilesString.Split(';');
            return returnList;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Task Entry Point.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public override bool Execute()
        {
            AbstractExecute();
            return !Log.HasLoggedErrors;
        }

        protected abstract bool AbstractExecute();
    }
}




namespace GranadaCoder.Framework.CrossDomain.MSBuild.Tasks.IO//.CustomFileKeepTask
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Security;

    using Microsoft.Build.Framework;
    using Microsoft.Build.Utilities;

    public class CustomFileKeepTask : FileBasedTaskBase
    {
        private static readonly string ROOT_DIRECTORY = "myrootdir";
        private static readonly string FULL_PATH = "myfullpath";
        private static readonly string FILE_NAME = "myfilename";
        private static readonly string DIRECTORY = "mydirectory";
        private static readonly string EXTENSION = "myextension";
        private static readonly string KEEPER = "mykeeper";

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the source files.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The source files.</value>
        [Required]
        public string SourceFiles { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the file versions as a Task Output property.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The file versions.</value>
        [Output]
        public ITaskItem[] FilteredFiles
        { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Task Entry Point.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        protected override bool AbstractExecute()
        {
            InternalExecute();
            return !Log.HasLoggedErrors;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Internal Execute Wrapper.
        /// </summary>
        private void InternalExecute()
        {
            IList<string> files = null;

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.SourceFiles))
            {
                Log.LogWarning("No SourceFiles specified");
                return;
            }

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.SourceFiles))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(this.SourceFiles);
                files = base.ConvertSourceFileStringToList(this.SourceFiles);
            }

            List<FileInfoWrapper> fiws = new List<FileInfoWrapper>();

            foreach (string f in files)
            {
                FileInfoWrapper fiw = null;
                fiw = this.DetermineExtraInformation(f);
                fiws.Add(fiw);
            }

            fiws = RunMyCustomKeeperLogic(fiws);

            ArrayList itemsAsStringArray = new ArrayList();

            foreach (var fiw in fiws.Where(x => x.IsAKeeper == true))
            {

                IDictionary currentMetaData = new System.Collections.Hashtable();
                currentMetaData.Add(ROOT_DIRECTORY, fiw.RootDirectory);
                currentMetaData.Add(FULL_PATH, fiw.FullPath);
                currentMetaData.Add(FILE_NAME, fiw.FileName);
                currentMetaData.Add(DIRECTORY, fiw.Directory);
                currentMetaData.Add(EXTENSION, fiw.Extension);

                string trueOrFalse = fiw.IsAKeeper.ToString();
                currentMetaData.Add(KEEPER, trueOrFalse);

                itemsAsStringArray.Add(new TaskItem(trueOrFalse, currentMetaData));
            }


            this.FilteredFiles = (ITaskItem[])itemsAsStringArray.ToArray(typeof(ITaskItem));
        }


        private List<FileInfoWrapper> RunMyCustomKeeperLogic(List<FileInfoWrapper> fiws)
        {
            int counter = 0;
            foreach (var fiw in fiws)
            {
                if(counter++ % 5 == 0)
                {
                    fiw.IsAKeeper = true;
                }
            }
            return fiws;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Determines the file version.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="fileName">Name of the file.</param>
        /// <returns>File version or 0.0.0.0 if value cannot be determined</returns>
        private FileInfoWrapper DetermineExtraInformation(string fileName)
        {
            FileInfoWrapper fiw = new FileInfoWrapper();
            fiw.Directory = string.Empty;
            fiw.Extension = string.Empty;
            fiw.FileName = string.Empty;
            fiw.FullPath = string.Empty;
            fiw.RootDirectory = string.Empty;
            fiw.IsAKeeper = false;
            try
            {
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileName))
                {
                    fiw.Extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileName);
                    fiw.FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName);
                    fiw.FullPath = fileName;// System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileName);
                    fiw.RootDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetPathRoot(fileName);

                    //Take the full path and remove the root directory to mimic the DotNet default behavior of '%filename'
                    fiw.Directory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName).Remove(0, fiw.RootDirectory.Length);

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (ex is IOException
                    || ex is UnauthorizedAccessException
                    || ex is PathTooLongException
                    || ex is DirectoryNotFoundException
                    || ex is SecurityException)
                {
                    Log.LogWarning("Error trying to determine file version " + fileName + ". " + ex.Message);
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.LogErrorFromException(ex);
                    throw;
                }
            }
            return fiw;
        }




        /// <summary>
        /// Internal wrapper class to hold file properties of interest.
        /// </summary>
        internal sealed class FileInfoWrapper
        {
            public string Directory { get; set; }
            public string Extension { get; set; }
            public string FileName { get; set; }
            public string FullPath { get; set; }
            public string RootDirectory { get; set; }
            public bool IsAKeeper { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

and here is an example .msbuild (or .proj or .xml) file to call the above.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="AllTargetsWrapper" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <UsingTask AssemblyFile="GranadaCoder.Framework.CrossDomain.MSBuild.dll" TaskName="CustomFileKeepTask"/>




  <Target Name="AllTargetsWrapper">
    <CallTarget Targets="CustomFileKeepTask1" />
    <CallTarget Targets="CustomFileKeepTask2" />
  </Target>


  <PropertyGroup>
    <WorkingCheckout>c:\Program Files\MSBuild</WorkingCheckout>
  </PropertyGroup>



  <ItemGroup>
    <MyTask1IncludeFiles Include="$(WorkingCheckout)\**\*.*" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="CustomFileKeepTask1">
    <CustomFileKeepTask SourceFiles="@(MyTask1IncludeFiles)" >

      <Output TaskParameter="FilteredFiles"  ItemName="MyFilteredFileItemNames"/>

    </CustomFileKeepTask>


    <Message Text=" MyFilteredFileItemNames MetaData  "/>
    <Message Text="  ------------------------------- "/>
    <Message Text="   "/>


    <Message Text="directory: "/>
    <Message Text="@(MyFilteredFileItemNames->'%(mydirectory)')"/>
    <Message Text="   "/>
    <Message Text="   "/>
    <Message Text="extension: "/>
    <Message Text="@(MyFilteredFileItemNames->'%(myextension)')"/>
    <Message Text="   "/>
    <Message Text="   "/>
    <Message Text="filename: "/>
    <Message Text="@(MyFilteredFileItemNames->'%(myfilename)')"/>
    <Message Text="   "/>
    <Message Text="   "/>
    <Message Text="fullpath: "/>
    <Message Text="@(MyFilteredFileItemNames->'%(myfullpath)')"/>
    <Message Text="   "/>
    <Message Text="   "/>
    <Message Text="rootdir: "/>
    <Message Text="@(MyFilteredFileItemNames->'%(myrootdir)')"/>
    <Message Text="   "/>
    <Message Text="   "/>

    <Message Text="FilteredFile: "/>
    <Message Text="@(MyFilteredFileItemNames->'%(mykeeper)')"/>
    <Message Text="   "/>
    <Message Text="   "/>


    <Message Text="   "/>
    <Message Text="   "/>
    <Message Text="rootdir + directory + filename + extension: "/>
    <Message Text="@(MyFilteredFileItemNames->'%(myrootdir)%(mydirectory)%(myfilename)%(myextension)')"/>
    <Message Text="   "/>
    <Message Text="   "/>



    <Message Text="List of files using special characters (carriage return)"/>
    <Message Text="@(MyFilteredFileItemNames->'&quot;%(myfullpath)&quot;' , '%0D%0A')"/>
    <Message Text="   "/>
    <Message Text="   "/>



  </Target>



  <ItemGroup>
    <MyTask2IncludeFiles Include="c:\windows\notepad.exe"  />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="CustomFileKeepTask2">
    <CustomFileKeepTask SourceFiles="@(MyTask2IncludeFiles)" >
      <Output TaskParameter="FilteredFiles" PropertyName="SingleFileFilteredFile"/>
    </CustomFileKeepTask>

    <Message Text="SingleFileFilteredFile = $(SingleFileFilteredFile)   "/>

  </Target>


</Project>
```

Comment: Yeah looks like a custom task might be the only way to do what I want using MSBuild, if I had the time I'd try to write one. 

(Not sure if I could use your exact example though as it seems to be choosing which files to build, not which output files to grab.)

For now though I'm just going to go through the 100 or so projects that produce executables and change their output folders {sigh}

Comment: My example is simply "tagging" the files........then outside of the Task, you can put those files in a "traditional" <Copy> command.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your example. To me it looks like it is "tagging" .cs files, where as what I want to do is get the list of all the built files in their relative folder structure.
If I have to specify every single file I wan't to move in a <Copy> I think I'm actually better off manually changing the 100 project outputs.

Comment: The "*.cs" has nothing to do with anything.  It's just a dumb example I did.  Also notice it is "MyTask1ExcludeFiles" (emphasis on the "Exclude")... I'll try to write out the logic by editing the original.

Comment: I removed the lines there were throwing you for a loop.  Basically, MyTask1IncludeFiles says "Get a list of all files in a certain directory"........then I push them through the custom task, and I tag some of them with a "IsAKeeper" boolean flag.  My logic is dumb, you'll have to write your own for your custom need.  Then, once these files are tagged inside the custom task...the (list of them) are available outside the task ... for you to run <Copy> or whatever you want on them.

Comment: Thanks for they trying, I'm sure I'm being stupid here but - doesn't this just get the source files?  I'm after the things that get built.  Also if I have to go list everything explicitly I am better off changing the project outputs in VS.

Comment: My example Task is just an example, it doesn't really do anything.  You would have to write custom logic to "tag" any files you want to keep.  Maybe files in a \Release\ folder?  I don't know your output directory structure, only you do.  Or you could pass all the .csproj files to the Task, parse the xml, find the output folders, and create a list of files that need to be tagged-for-copy.  The point of the custom Task is your write your own logic for what you want it to do.  I wrote an example Task, just to get you started.  I don't know what your custom logic should be, that's up to you.